# Dynamic Properties Generation worked with intellisense

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, intellisense, customization

I would like create a "dynamic" class. This class should load its properties from a database. Of course everything needs to function with intellisense for my dear colleagues.

I already tried some mix with dynamic class and customtypediscriptor. But nothing works well.

I start to doubt: Is it possible to generate a library that will contain my class and, at each build, my class properties will be updated from a database?

Comment: Try T4 templates. You can build classes/code from a db.